# how do I ensure a custom UIView I have is repositioned properly after an orientation change of the iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, interface-builder, xcode4, uiinterfaceorientation

how do I ensure a custom UIView I have is repositioned properly after an orientation change of the iPhone?

Background

- As a parent view I have a UIViewController with an XIB
- I have a custom UIView which is used in this parent (inserted in the XIB via Interface Builder).  It programmatically at init creates some UIImageView's and adds them via "self addSubview", and then positions them via "self addSubview:imageView1" type approach

So the questions are how do I ensure I get the correct layout of these as orientation changes.  Specifically:

1. Where do I trigger any such redrawing of the custom UIView?  (e.g. is there a method in the parent UIViewController I should be using to trigger from?)
2. When the trigger occurs how do I request the redraw of the custom UIView?  Do I need a custom method I create myself like "relayoutCustomView"?  or should I be able to use an existing method in the custom UIView, in which case do I need to make sure in the custom UIView that my layout code is in a particular method?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how's this for the answer - seems to be starting to work, not sure if it's the best way:

1. separate out the layout code in my custom view and put in a separate method and make this public
2. this method will be called from within the custom view "init" method upon setup
3. also now however create an "didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation" method in the parent, and from within here also call into the new custom view layout method mentioned in [1]
4. noted it had to be "didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation", as with the "didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation" method it didn't work as the self.bounds result hadn't yet changed

How does this sound?   I didn't use the "setNeedsDisplay" anywhere...

Comment: Before you do too much you might just want to play around with the resizing masks for your view and the items in it. If your views are built in XIBs then it is very easy to do this and see the results. If it is in code it takes a little bit more time but is still not very hard.

Comment: so for my custom UI view I don't have an XIB - so I think you're suggesting even then I could programmatically setup and use the auto resizing features?  is this what you mean sosborn?

Comment: Yeah. I mean, it is hard to give a definitive answer because I don't know what you view contains and how you want it to layout when it resizes, but in general the autoresizing masks take a lot of pain out of laying things out after a reorientation.